# Access Token is null when set up Facebook with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I take the problem when try to set up Facebook login.

In client side, my javacript code is:

```
FB.init({
    appId: 'my id',
    cookie: true,
    version: 'v2.2'
});

FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        alert('You are logged in & cookie set!');
        window.location.replace("/user/logInWithFacebookID");
    } else {
        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
});
```

It works. The page display facebook pop-up and I clicked allow in facebook form. The page also display alert before go to server's function (logInWithFacebookID).

In server side, my function is:

```
//initialization
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'my id',
    'app_secret' => 'my secret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();

$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

When I debug to getAccessToken line, accessToken is null. I think cookie is not set, but I turned on cookie in fb object's init function.

Comment: What version of the Facebook PHP SDK are you using?

Comment: I use composer to get Facebook SDK. It is currently v4.

Comment: I'd first suggest updating to the latest version, check the documentation how to do what you're doing, and in case it is not working, file a bug report https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0